# Can anyone help to fix curl: (7) Failed to connect to port 80: Connection refused

Tags: docker, curl

I use ubuntu 18.04 LTS on google cloud.
I face this error while I am trying to learn Docker and Container.

Here are the steps I took:

1. I wrote the following PHP code:

   `<?php echo "Welcome";?>`
2. Created a docker file, I wrote the following instructions:

   ```
   FROM php:7.4-cli
   COPY code.php /var/www/html
   EXPOSE 80
   ```
3. I built an image using the command:

   `sudo docker build .`
4. I tagged and gave a new name to the new build:

   `sudo docker tag f7bddf273402 newp`
5. I created a container using the command below:

   `sudo docker run -d -it --name mywebc -p 10.128.0.8:80:80 newp`
6. I then tried connecting to the container above with the following command:

   `curl 10.128.0.8:80`

And then I got the following error:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.128.0.8 port 80: Connection refused`

Comment: complete you question, or better to add minimal reproducible example

Comment: Please take a look at [VPC firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) and make sure that port 80 is accessible on that machine in general.

Comment: Can you post the output of docker ps?